# Is it possible to show my cover has no finite subcover?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I am currently trying to show that the set $S = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$ is not compact by showing the cover
$$
\mathcal{C} = \left\{ \left( \frac{p}{q} - \frac{1}{10^q!}, \frac{p}{q} + \frac{1}{10^q!} \right) \right\}_{p/q \in S}
$$
admits no finite subcover, with the assumption that each $\frac{p}{q} \in S$ is written such that $\gcd(p, q) = 1$.

I know there are far easier methods (contradict closedness with an irrational limit point) and covers to try this with, but I am very much so determined to do something with this specific cover.

So far, I have determined that for $a \in S$ to be contained within an interval for some other $b \in S$, the denominator of $a$ must be greater than that of $b$, with the whole idea being that if a theoretical finite subcover does exist, it always requires at least one more to cover some endpoint of an interval, thus leading to a contradiction.

My main questions are:

1. Is this even true for this cover?
2. If so, are there any decent hints that could push me in the right direction?

Comment: A proof sketch: one thing you could do is compute the sum of lengths of these intervals. If you have a finite cover, then the total lengths of the intervals in that cover must be bounded above by the sum of all lengths. So, if you have a union of finitely many intervals in $[0, 1]$ with the sum of lengths strictly smaller than $1$, then the complement must be a nonempty union of finitely many intervals as well, so the complement must contain a rational number.

Comment: @DavidGao I considered this, but does it work? My main reason for disbelieving it is because in the infinite case, the entire sum is less than 1 already. But, we know it covers all the rationals. I'm not advanced enough to know why (something to do with Lebesgue measures?) but that's my intuition behind why that isn't a sufficient method. If it is, where does my intuition fail?

Comment: Well, it does feel a bit weird to have an open cover containing all rationals but that somehow is not everything. But that is exactly what happens here. The open cover doesn't cover all irrationals, that's all. It's hard to explicitly exhibit an example an irrational number not contained in the cover, but for a similar example, consider the complement of a fat Cantor set, which is open dense but has total length strictly smaller than 1.

Comment: As to why a finite subcover cannot cover even all rationals, the distinction lies between what a complement of an infinite union of open intervals can be versus what a complement of a finite union of open intervals can be. The first case can be any closed set, which could contain no nontrivial interval but still have positive length (again, a fat Cantor set is a good example). Whereas in the second case, you can prove (by induction, for example), that the complement is a union of intervals plus possibly finitely many extra points...

Comment: In such cases, having positive length necessarily means one of the intervals is nontrivial - but then it has to contain a rational number. The main distinction, again, is really that in general you could have a positive measure set with no interior, but that could not happen if your set is a union of intervals (which is the case for the complement of finitely many intervals).

Comment: Suggestion: try finding an infinite cover of open sets that do not overlap. For example $(-1, \pi -3) \cap \Bbb Q, (\pi-3,2)\cap \Bbb Q$ is an open cover of $\cal C$ with no overlap, Just find an infinite version of the idea. Since there is no overlap, all the sets are needed to be a cover.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGao, I'll talk about this more with my professor and try to understand it better. Many thanks!